# Gnome-logs important warnings (20.04)

Tags: logs

I am rumming 20.04 having upgraded from 19.10. On boot up my Gnome-Log list the following four important warnings:

```
Hardware: pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout   
Other: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file 
Hardware: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS 
System: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
```

Does anyone know how to fix one or all of these warnings

Edit: Result of sudo grep -i AER /var/log/syslog*

```
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:38:25    kernel: [ 2112.333692] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:38:25    kernel: [ 2112.333717] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:38:25    kernel: [ 2112.333729] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:38:25    kernel: [ 2112.333737] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:45:41    kernel: [ 2548.495211] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:45:41    kernel: [ 2548.495232] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:45:41    kernel: [ 2548.495241] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 09:45:41    kernel: [ 2548.495246] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:00:17    kernel: [ 3424.914424] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:00:17    kernel: [ 3424.914447] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:00:17    kernel: [ 3424.914456] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:00:17    kernel: [ 3424.914461] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:32:38    kernel: [ 5365.540516] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:32:38    kernel: [ 5365.540538] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:32:38    kernel: [ 5365.540545] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:32:38    kernel: [ 5365.540550] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:35:10    kernel: [ 5517.598490] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:35:10    kernel: [ 5517.598511] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:35:10    kernel: [ 5517.598518] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 10:35:10    kernel: [ 5517.598523] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:08:03    kernel: [ 7490.357204] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:08:03    kernel: [ 7490.357222] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:08:03    kernel: [ 7490.357227] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:08:03    kernel: [ 7490.357230] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:55:48    kernel: [10355.729066] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:55:48    kernel: [10355.729091] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:55:48    kernel: [10355.729100] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 11:55:48    kernel: [10355.729107] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:02:08    kernel: [10735.692104] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:02:08    kernel: [10735.692128] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:02:08    kernel: [10735.692138] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:02:08    kernel: [10735.692145] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:04:08    kernel: [10856.011819] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:04:08    kernel: [10856.011840] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:04:08    kernel: [10856.011846] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:04:08    kernel: [10856.011851] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:18:08    kernel: [11695.963571] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:18:08    kernel: [11695.963592] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:18:08    kernel: [11695.963599] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:18:08    kernel: [11695.963604] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:55:33    kernel: [13940.856114] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:55:33    kernel: [13940.856133] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:55:33    kernel: [13940.856144] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 12:55:33    kernel: [13940.856152] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:09:14    kernel: [14761.290891] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:09:14    kernel: [14761.290912] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:09:14    kernel: [14761.290919] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:09:14    kernel: [14761.290924] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:22:54    kernel: [15581.750396] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:22:54    kernel: [15581.750419] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:22:54    kernel: [15581.750428] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 13:22:54    kernel: [15581.750436] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 14:01:07    kernel: [17874.670685] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 14:01:07    kernel: [17874.670752] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 14:01:07    kernel: [17874.670759] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 14:01:07    kernel: [17874.670763] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:05:53    kernel: [    0.302749] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:05:53    kernel: [    1.246204] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:05:53    kernel: [    1.246689] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:05:53    kernel: [    1.247155] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:52:35    kernel: [ 2807.311812] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:52:35    kernel: [ 2807.311826] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:52:35    kernel: [ 2807.311828] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 15:52:35    kernel: [ 2807.311829] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:19:59    kernel: [ 4451.886604] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:19:59    kernel: [ 4451.886624] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:19:59    kernel: [ 4451.886632] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:19:59    kernel: [ 4451.886637] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:28:57    kernel: [ 4990.073432] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:28:57    kernel: [ 4990.073454] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:28:57    kernel: [ 4990.073462] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:28:57    kernel: [ 4990.073468] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:47:22    kernel: [ 6094.485311] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:47:22    kernel: [ 6094.485335] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:47:22    kernel: [ 6094.485344] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 16:47:22    kernel: [ 6094.485351] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 17:12:59    kernel: [ 7631.201166] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 17:12:59    kernel: [ 7631.201187] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 17:12:59    kernel: [ 7631.201194] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 17:12:59    kernel: [ 7631.201199] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:25:24    kernel: [11976.939762] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:25:24    kernel: [11976.939786] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:25:24    kernel: [11976.939797] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:25:24    kernel: [11976.939804] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:30:59    kernel: [12311.582585] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:30:59    kernel: [12311.582605] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:30:59    kernel: [12311.582615] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:30:59    kernel: [12311.582622] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:32:59    kernel: [12431.466043] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:32:59    kernel: [12431.466062] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:32:59    kernel: [12431.466070] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:32:59    kernel: [12431.466076] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:33:56    kernel: [12489.130439] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:33:56    kernel: [12489.130461] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:33:56    kernel: [12489.130469] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 18:33:56    kernel: [12489.130474] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:18:49    kernel: [15182.096585] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:18:49    kernel: [15182.096609] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:18:49    kernel: [15182.096621] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:18:49    kernel: [15182.096630] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:33:58    kernel: [16090.404395] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:33:58    kernel: [16090.404415] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:33:58    kernel: [16090.404425] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:33:58    kernel: [16090.404432] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:41:00    kernel: [16512.597276] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:41:00    kernel: [16512.597293] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:41:00    kernel: [16512.597296] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 19:41:00    kernel: [16512.597299] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:32:43    kernel: [19616.044249] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:32:43    kernel: [19616.044264] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:32:43    kernel: [19616.044267] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:32:43    kernel: [19616.044270] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:41:03    kernel: [20116.212322] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:41:03    kernel: [20116.212338] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:41:03    kernel: [20116.212343] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:41:03    kernel: [20116.212381] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:48:16    kernel: [20548.388744] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:48:16    kernel: [20548.388767] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:48:16    kernel: [20548.388776] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 20:48:16    kernel: [20548.388782] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:38:03    kernel: [23535.317470] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:38:03    kernel: [23535.317491] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:38:03    kernel: [23535.317499] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:38:03    kernel: [23535.317504] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:45:37    kernel: [23989.480880] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:45:37    kernel: [23989.480901] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:45:37    kernel: [23989.480910] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:45:37    kernel: [23989.480915] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:01:09    kernel: [24921.815861] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:01:09    kernel: [24921.815882] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:01:09    kernel: [24921.815889] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:01:09    kernel: [24921.815894] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:02:25    kernel: [24997.844261] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:02:25    kernel: [24997.844281] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:02:25    kernel: [24997.844290] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:02:25    kernel: [24997.844298] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:07:45    kernel: [25317.969850] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:07:45    kernel: [25317.969870] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:07:45    kernel: [25317.969877] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:07:45    kernel: [25317.969883] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:18:53    kernel: [25986.200037] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:18:53    kernel: [25986.200076] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:18:53    kernel: [25986.200084] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 22:18:53    kernel: [25986.200090] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 08:34:00    kernel: [    0.301707] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 08:34:00    kernel: [    1.225656] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 08:34:00    kernel: [    1.226112] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 08:34:00    kernel: [    1.226549] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:18:53    kernel: [ 2697.157606] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:18:53    kernel: [ 2697.157627] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:18:53    kernel: [ 2697.157634] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:18:53    kernel: [ 2697.157640] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:21:21    kernel: [ 2845.220042] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:21:21    kernel: [ 2845.220062] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:21:21    kernel: [ 2845.220069] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:21:21    kernel: [ 2845.220074] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:26:57    kernel: [ 3181.350293] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:26:57    kernel: [ 3181.350311] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:26:57    kernel: [ 3181.350319] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:26:57    kernel: [ 3181.350325] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:29:37    kernel: [ 3341.414226] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:29:37    kernel: [ 3341.414246] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:29:37    kernel: [ 3341.414253] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 09:29:37    kernel: [ 3341.414258] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:05:10    kernel: [    0.303700] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:05:10    kernel: [    1.250362] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:05:10    kernel: [    1.250826] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:05:10    kernel: [    1.251276] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:31:14    kernel: [ 1569.476749] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:31:14    kernel: [ 1569.476771] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:31:14    kernel: [ 1569.476778] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 12:31:14    kernel: [ 1569.476784] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:29:22    kernel: [ 5056.862044] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:29:22    kernel: [ 5056.862065] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:29:22    kernel: [ 5056.862072] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:29:22    kernel: [ 5056.862077] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:33:55    kernel: [    0.302831] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:33:55    kernel: [    1.246804] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:33:55    kernel: [    1.247281] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:33:55    kernel: [    1.247748] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 18:32:33    kernel: [    0.298382] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 18:32:33    kernel: [    1.221683] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 18:32:33    kernel: [    1.222139] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 18:32:33    kernel: [    1.222573] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:28:42    kernel: [    0.304403] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:28:42    kernel: [    1.249976] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:28:42    kernel: [    1.250430] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:28:42    kernel: [    1.250863] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:37:31    kernel: [    0.302937] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:37:31    kernel: [    1.225075] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 122
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:37:31    kernel: [    1.225527] pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:37:31    kernel: [    1.225960] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:40:42    kernel: [  196.724856] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:40:42    kernel: [  196.724876] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:40:42    kernel: [  196.724889] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a336] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 20:40:42    kernel: [  196.724897] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [12] Timeout               
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 22:55:00    dbus-daemon[7748]: [session uid=0 pid=7746] Activating service name='org.a11y.Bus' requested by ':1.1' (uid=0 pid=7742 comm="gedit AER /var/log/syslog /var/log/syslog.1 /var/l" label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 22:55:00    dbus-daemon[7748]: [session uid=0 pid=7746] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=7742 comm="gedit AER /var/log/syslog /var/log/syslog.1 /var/l" label="unconfined")
Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei /var/log/syslog.3.gz
Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei /var/log/syslog.5.gz
Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei /var/log/syslog.6.gz
```

Comment: I have stopped the "Hardware: pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: " warning by adding "pcie_aspm=off" to the line 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"' in the file  /etc/default/grub

Comment: That's not a good fix. It just masks the errors, but the errors still occur. Let's see how bad the problem is... edit your question and show me `sudo gedit -i AER /var/log/syslog*`... if that output is lengthy, paste it at paste.ubuntu.com. Also show me `sudo lspci -nn`.

Comment: That first command results in "Unknown Option -i" Running the command without the option results in this warning in the terminal after closng the window: "(gedit:7871): Tepl-WARNING **: 22:56:17.375: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.

Comment: Oops! That's what happens when you're helping multiple people at once... gedit should be grep. Sorry. `sudo grep -i AER /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo lspci -nn`.

Comment: Also please show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `uname -r`, and tell me the make/model of your computer.

Comment: @ heynnema  I have added the result of 'sudo grep -i AER /var/log/syslog*'. My computer is a TUXEDO BC1707 Linux only laptop from https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/de/Linux-Hardware/Linux-Notebooks/Alle.tuxedo#!#1275,1325 BIOS-version is 1.07.08 uname -r gives "5.4.0-31-generic"

Comment: Steve, thanks for the info, but you forgot the `lspci -nn`. That will help me identify what device is causing your AER errors. I went to check for an updated BIOS, but at https://www.tuxedocomputers.com they want you to log into your account there to see the downloads. Please check there for a newer BIOS, as that could also solve the problem. Report back.

Comment: OK, pasted the result of lspci -nn at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MHKK76BPkv/

Comment: Steve, thanks again for the info. Unfortunately it wasn't specific enough, so I need to see `lspci -tv` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Thanks.

Comment: Steve, to try and solve "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed", in `terminal` please do `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`. This will rebuild the ramdisk file that gets loaded at boot time.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DTFTmtyMCj/

Comment: Funny enough, PCI device 1d.6 is actually two devices, a card reader, or an ethernet card. You don't have anything in the card reader, correct? I'll still need more info to be able to make a recommendation. Why don't you upload /var/log/syslog and /var/log/syslog.1 to paste.ubuntu.com and I'll try and slog though all of that and get back to you.

Comment: Did you have time to go to the web site and check for a newer BIOS?

Comment: Hi Heynnema, actually I do have a SD card in the card reader which I use for backups. I will try booting with that removed. Thanks for your help but as this particular issue isn't actually causing me any issues other than the warning I think I'll just leave it for now.

Comment: Remove the card from the reader, remove pcie_aspm=off, reboot, and monitor /var/log/syslog for more AER errors. Personally, I'd go a little further, to try and finalize the cause of the error(s). You can easily check for a newer BIOS, and do the update-initramfs command. Let me know if you wish to continue at all. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, but I'm a bit pressed at the moment. I'll keep looking into things as I find the time and if I do find out what the problem is, you'll be the first to know what was causing it.

Comment: Fair enough. I suspect the SD card, due to the timeouts.

Comment: @heynnema Hi. I'm having same issues but with my NVIDIA dedicated GPU (in a laptop). Also when I enable it in NVIDIA X Server Settings, I see`GPU has fallen off the bus` error. More: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304696/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus-on-almost-every-boot

Comment: @adazem009 See my comments on your other question.