# GPU has fallen off the bus (on almost every boot)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

- **Device:** HP ProBook 470 G4
- **Integrated GPU:** Intel HD Graphics 620
- **Dedicated GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce 930MX

My laptop just returned from a service center (because of a CPU failure). Everything was working well before the CPU failed. Now, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

**Note:** I tried EVERY version of the driver. My GPU supports **390, 418, 430, 435, 440, 450 and 455**. There's also a strange thing... when I install 440, APT installs 450. Same happens for 430 and 418. 435 is being replaced by 455. Anyway, here's my problem:

When I boot my laptop, it gets stuck on a black screen **before gdm3 starts**. I can't even switch the TTY. Only SSH is working. When I got the dmesg log, I saw this:

```
[   16.620560] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PXSX._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found
[Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20200528/nsarguments-59)
[   17.126534] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[   17.126546] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[   18.695141] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[   18.695154] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)                     
[   18.695159] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:9d10] error status/mask=00100000/00010000                                                     
[   18.695161] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [20] UnsupReq               (First)                                                                       
[   18.695164] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   TLP Header: 34000000 00000010 00000000 00000000                                                            
[   18.695173] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
[   18.695208] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: device recovery failed
[   18.699191] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-9fe5f99e-479c-1100-e75b-dc4310990232
[   18.699194] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=1521, GPU has fallen off the bus.                                                                    
[   18.699197] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
[   18.699206] NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
               NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
               NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
[   19.031183] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   19.423191] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[   19.423195] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Tainted: P           OE     5.8.0-050800-generic #202008022230
[   19.423195] Hardware name: HP HP ProBook 470 G4/8234, BIOS P85 Ver. 01.37 10/19/2020
[   19.423196] Call Trace:
[   19.423197]  <IRQ>
[   19.423202]  dump_stack+0x70/0x8d
[   19.423205]  __report_bad_irq+0x3a/0xaf
[   19.423206]  note_interrupt.cold+0x8/0x60
[   19.423208]  handle_irq_event+0xaa/0xb1
[   19.423208]  handle_fasteoi_irq+0x7d/0x1c0
[   19.423210]  asm_call_on_stack+0x12/0x20
[   19.423211]  </IRQ>
[   19.423213]  common_interrupt+0xbc/0x160
[   19.423214]  asm_common_interrupt+0x1e/0x40
[   19.423215] RIP: 0010:poll_idle+0x9b/0xb9
[   19.423217] Code: 44 89 e8 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 4c 89 f7 48 89 de e8 77 71 dd ff 49 89 c6 b8 c9 00 00 00 49 8b 17 83 e2 08 75 b1 f3 90 <83> e8 01 75 f1 65 8b 3d 59 97 04 63 e8 34 f6 51 ff 4c 29 e0 4c 39
[   19.423217] RSP: 0018:ffffa8f3000ffe10 EFLAGS: 00000246
[   19.423218] RAX: 0000000000000020 RBX: ffff9b8bc05b7500 RCX: 000000000000001f
[   19.423219] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9b8bc05b7500 RDI: ffffffff9df6d760
[   19.423219] RBP: ffffa8f3000ffe38 R08: 0000000485b61e74 R09: 0000000000000001
[   19.423220] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffff9b8bc05ab364 R12: 0000000485b61e74
[   19.423221] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00000000000007d0 R15: ffff9b8bb5300000
[   19.423223]  cpuidle_enter_state+0x81/0x3f0
[   19.423224]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
[   19.423226]  cpuidle_idle_call+0x145/0x200
[   19.423227]  do_idle+0x7a/0xe0
[   19.423228]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
[   19.423230]  start_secondary+0xe6/0x100
[   19.423232]  secondary_startup_64+0xb6/0xc0
[   19.423233] handlers:
[   19.423236] [<00000000750c932b>] i801_isr [i2c_i801]
[   19.423237] Disabling IRQ #16
```

I can always `sudo prime-select intel && sudo systemctl restart gdm3` using SSH to get the display manager working, but the NVIDIA card just doesn't work.

**Note:** I don't think this is indicates a GPU failure. I can get the GPU working by adding some boot arguments. For example, I tried these:

```
quiet splash rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1 acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' pci=nomsi
```

Adding the arguments **fixed the issue, but only for 1 boot**. So, when I started my laptop, everything was working fine, even suspending. The GPU was working so I know it isn't failing. Also it's working fine in Windows.
When I restart my laptop, it gets stuck on the black screen again (yes, I updated grub to make the changes permanent).

**nomsi** disables MSI, but it doesn't solve my issue. The GPU still "falls of the bus", but with different error messages (failed to enable MSI).

Is there a way to maybe disable the PCIe errors so the NVIDIA driver doesn't crash? I really think it's crashing because the kernel spams it with error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:** I tried the irqpoll option but it didn't fix anything...
An odd thing here is everything works fine in Windows. It's just Ubuntu (I might try other distros if necessary). I can't open the laptop's case because it would void the repair warranty.

**Edit 2:** Output of `lspci -tv`:

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
           +-1c.0-[01]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
           +-1c.4-[02]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-1c.5-[03]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
           +-1d.0-[04]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
           +-1c.0-[01]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
           +-1c.4-[02]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-1c.5-[03]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
           +-1d.0-[04]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci -tv`. Remove "rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1 acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' pci=nomsi" and `sudo update-grub`. Your Nvidia driver should be 460.39, see https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/

Comment: @heynnema Yes, my driver version is 460. I didn't mention it because I asked this question before the new version came out. It's same on all releases anyway.

Comment: Please see my answer. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a hardware issue. I'm not sure what's wrong with the GPU but I think it's attached to the motherboard incorrectly. I'll try to disassemble the laptop and see what's wrong. If I'm not able to fix it, I'll take the laptop to a service center again.

My tests:

- It wasn't happening before
- It started to happen in Windows too now (I got something like error 46 in the device manager)
- It doesn't happen on every boot. Sometimes the GPU works, but it stops working on the next restart, hibernation or suspend.
- I'm experiencing random PCIe bus errors (>100 dmesg messages per second) even when the Intel GPU is selected. Removing the GPU from the kernel (by writing 1 to `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/remove` solves this issue without a reboot.

Comment: You may need to send it back to the Service Center.

Answer (score 0):

Device 1c.0 is causing the problem... and the AER (Advanced Error Reporting) is reporting it...

```
       +-1c.0-[01]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
```

Although, like you, I suspect a hardware problem, for testing purposes, we can try this...

**AER**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

Save the file.

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Otherwise, you'll need to send it back to the Service Center.

Comment: Hi. I've already tried this. It just hides the errors but the GPU still "falls off the bus". I've also tried kernel options like `pcie_aspm=off`, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: @adazem009 Send it back to the Service Center.

Comment: I think I'll try to repair it myself because I can't afford more repairs. I looked at some disassembly videos for this laptop and I think I can check what's wrong with the GPU easily. I'll buy a new laptop in about 2 years anyway...

Comment: @adazem009 You may void the service warranty if you open the laptop. I'd bring it back and let THEM check it out.

Comment: I disassembled the laptop when the CPU failed and it wasn't in warranty anyway. It's a 3 year old laptop and I took it to an unofficial service center. They replaced the CPU and now the laptop works. There are problems like caps lock + num lock blinks 5 times before boot. Also the dedicated GPU has issues.

Comment: @adazem009 if the num lock blinks 5 times, that indicates a hard failure. Look in the User Manual to see what 5 blinks means.